# Where does Gradle managed dependency without Maven or Ivy?

Tags: java, maven, gradle, dependency-management

I understand that usually Java projects using Gradle are publishing their reusable code by publishing the Maven's `pom.xml` file along side with the jar file. However I'm wondering where Gradle store the dependency list if the library is not published using neither Ivy nor Maven. Moreover, Gradle can be used not only for JVM-based project, but it can also be used to build non-JVM project, which obviously does not use Maven or Ivy.

I've read [Chapter 23. Dependency Management](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html) but it doesn't give a clue how Gradle can publish Java library without Maven or Ivy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Transitive dependencies for native projects in Gradle are not possible as of Gradle 2.13.**

You would need to implement your own plugin that would somehow store/retrieve and process such metadata and use them correctly (resolve, download and put the files into correct directories).

We plan to implement similar functionality. The closest to the solution is [Maven NAR plugin](http://maven-nar.github.io/).